# Can ref and Out keyword can decide method overloading

Tags: c#

I have a question regarding  method overlading given below
Fun1(int a);
Fun1(ref int a);

Is this method overloading? IF Yes then WHY and if No then WHY?

Comment: Have you read the documentations about it?..

Comment: The difference is: `Fun1(int a)` => pass by value, `Fun1(ref int a)` => pass by reference. Passing with both ways resulting different behavior against `a` value .

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation:

> Methods can be overloaded when one method has a ref or out parameter and the other has a value parameter

So the answer to your question is yes, but why?

As per definition of function overloading:

> Function overloading (also called method overloading) is a programming concept that allows programmers to define two or more functions with the same name and in the same scope. Each function has a unique signature (or header), which is derived from:

1. function/procedure name
2. number of arguments
3. **arguments' type**
4. arguments' order

When you are passing a parameter without using the ref keyword you are actually passing a reference to the variable thus the type of argument is different from that when passed without ref keyword.

```
    public void function(ref int abc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Result Ref: " + abc);
    }

    public void function(int abc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Result: " + abc);
    }
```

Thus the signature of the above two functions is not the same as the type of argument passed to the both is not the same.

Hope I was able to satisfy you with my answer :).

Also I would like to add another point to the discussion that overloading is not possible in case of using out with one function and ref with another as in this case both the types are considered as same so no overloading in the following case:

```
    public void function(ref int abc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Result Ref: " + abc);
    }

    public void function(out int abc)
    {
        abc = 1221;
        Console.WriteLine("Result Out: " + abc);
    }
```

Comment: Always Happy To Help

Answer (score 0):

```
1) Fun1(int a); 
2) Fun1(ref int a);
```

1 and 2 are different functions. 1 - pass by value, 2 - pass by reference.

For example:

```
    public static void Func(int i)
    {
        i++;
        Console.WriteLine("int a = {0}", i);
    }
    public static void Func(ref int i)
    {
        i++;
        Console.WriteLine("ref int a = {0}", i);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a = 9;
        Func(ref a);
        // Func(a);
        Console.WriteLine("a = {0}", a);
        Console.Read();
    }
```

output:

> ref int a = 10
>
> a = 10

it means that `a` is passed by reference and function `Func(ref int i)` can change its value.

in second case when you call `Func(a)` in `Main` function result is:

> int a = 10
>
> a = 9

It means that `a` is passed by value.
You can implement both functions in one class․

Comment: Thank you so much..that means in Fun1(int a) it is passed by value and other one Fun1(ref int a) it is passed by reference..this is the reason, right?

Comment: @ANUJ yes. Pass by reference when you want to change value in Main function